# Как расширять структуру / класс вне его / ее объявления?

Tags: c++, классы, объекты

Никак не могу понять как на примере интерпретатора python можно расширять главный PyObject дополняя его методами и другими объектами не правя саму внутренность в определении структуры?

вот пример:

```
static PyObject * null_error(void)
{
    if (!PyErr_Occurred())
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_SystemError,
                        "null argument to internal routine");
    return NULL;
}
```

Как вообще это работает или как хотя бы называется правильно такая конструкция с звездочкой? Для плюсовых классов картина такая же?

Comment: Где в этом примере вообще какое-то "расширение класса"? Почему вы решили, что здесь кто-то что-то "расширяет"? Здесь обычная функция возвращает указатель `PyObject *`. Никакого "расширения" в упор не видно.

Comment: @AnT окей, значит мимо с примером. Тогда вопрос остается, как в питоне дописывается функционал? Я же вызываю сишные функции сторонних модулей в питоне через его PyObject вроде как раз в питоне все из них (объектов(функции, переменные, код)) состоит, верно?

Comment: @Ljachowsky, давай развёрнуто и по порядку, что именно делаешь и что именно смущает, а то питон в кучу с Си да крестами смешан и непонятно о чём вообще вопрос...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, думаю тут нужно знать и Пайтон, чтобы понять его вопрос

Comment: @AnT хорошо. Я хочу понять как добавлять функционал в виде методов в класс/структуру внее ее реализации (т.е. не внутри фигурных скобок типа "class Foo{ public: void func(); }; ") В пример была приведена первая попавшиеся функция которая мне как показалась редактирует сам PyObject "добавляясь" в нее. Пример с такой внутренней структурой интерпретатора как по мне самый наглядный, так как через PyObject вызывается абсолютно все, хоть написанное самим, хоть стандартные функции из стандартной библиотеки. Вот и хочу понять как можно создать объект, а потом добавлять функционал не трогая определение

Comment: @Ljachowsky: В С++ нельзя ничего добавить в класс после того, как его определение завершено. Какое-то подобие "добавления" могут выполнять перегружаемые операторы, но и они могут работать только через существующий внешний интерфейс класса.

Comment: Добавлять можно  в производных классах и работать с ними указательями на родительский класс. Этот указатель будет иметь адрес начала каждого обьекта

Comment: Вы хотите реализовать организацию объектов C++ как в питоне с динамическим добавлением / удалением свойств и функций в них?  Или вам надо добавлять свойства и функции объектов питона из C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct PyObject  {
   virtual  bool PyErr_Occurred()  = 0;
   virtual PyObject* null_error() = 0;
};
struct D : PyObject {
    // добавим обьект
    int k = 5;
    virtual  bool PyErr_Occurred() final { return this;}
    virtual PyObject* null_error() override
     {
         if (!PyErr_Occurred())
             throw "null argument to internal routine";
         std::cout << '\t' << k << std::endl;
         return this;
     }
};
struct D1 : D {
    // добавим обьекты
    std::string s = "D1";
    int n = 3;
    char c = 'c';
    //добавим функционал
    void foo() { std::cout << s << "::" << c << std::endl; }
    virtual PyObject* null_error() final
     {
         foo();
         return this;
     }
};
```

Указатель на `PyObject` может содержать начало адреса обьектов  любого производного класса. Мы можем добавлять классы в иерархии, можем изменять и добавлять функции, обьекты в классах, при этом не трогать базовый класс и сам код. Например:

```
int main()
{    
    D d; D1 d1;
    PyObject *p  = &d, *q = &d1;
    try {
       p->null_error();
       q ->null_error();
       cout << p->PyErr_Occurred() << endl << q->null_error() << endl;
    }
    catch (const char* p) {
        cerr << p;
    }
    cout << &d1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Этот код не будет зависеть от того, что вы измените в классах и в их функциях. Вам это интересовало?...

Comment: Да, это всего лишь грубый пример, можно написать куда более оссмысленные примеры